# OpacityMask missing in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

Any easy way to apply `OpacityMask` to a UI object in UWP XAML?

I used to do that in WPF but appears to be missing in UWP.

Comment: Please, avoid the offensive tone... StackOverflow rules are just trying to achieve a good Q&A quality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can partially replicate this functionality, but not in an especially easy way. `Windows Composition API` offers a similar functionality where you can define a `CompositionMaskBrush` with which you will "paint over" the UI object to achieve a opacity mask effect.

There is an example as [the solution of a GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsUIDevLabs/issues/128) that demonstrates such process. The same user also [asked on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361081/uwp-composition-apply-opacity-mask-to-top-30px-of-a-listview).

You can also check out the [CompositionProToolkit](https://github.com/ratishphilip/CompositionProToolkit) that might simplify implementing this.